# Access SQL Server Analysis Services Remotely for Data Mining Tool

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server Enterprise trial in one computer. I want to use that the Analysis Sevices of that computer as a backend for using the data mining tool for excel in other computers. I was able to do it when I was using two computers in same network logged on with same username. But, the backend computer with SQL Server will be in a networked computer with a domain name while the excel users will not be logged in as domain users (just a regular local computer users) from outside the network. I will have vpn set up so that those users will be connected to the network as if it was a LAN connection.

How can I add, non-domain users as users in SQL Server Analysis Services (interestingly this seem to be different than SQL Server DB Server).

Please please please.

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a lot of work but I have done it in the past and it is quite simple. You basically create a HTTP endpoint in IIS that your excel clients connect to. The endpoint allows basic authentication while IIS authenticates with the cube on a predefined account. Full instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx)